# Split list at '0' into two lists

Tags: python, list, matrix

I have a list:

```
matrix = [1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 6]
```

which needs to be split into a random amount of lists at 0 (ignoring 0):

```
matrix1 = [3, 2, 1]
matrix2 = [4, 5]
matrix3 = [6]
```

How would I go about doing this? The original list will be of random length and with random numbers.

Comment: I think you can find this http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm useful, in your case about modifying and looping lists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = [1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 6]
[list(g) for k, g in groupby(lst, lambda x: x != 0) if k]
# [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]
```

Comment: What do 'k' and 'g' mean in this context?

Comment: `groupby` generates an iterable of tuples, the first element of the tuple is the key, the second element of the tuple is the grouped elements, so k, g are the key and grouped elements correspondingly, to see this better, you can check these two expressions `[(k, list(g)) for k, g in groupby(lst, lambda x: x!= 0)]` and `list(groupby(lst, lambda x: x!=0))`